# using paste0 in R with text and dataframe column, but without text repeating

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

Here is some sample code:

```
df1<-data.frame(Name=c("John","Steve","Andy"),
                Age=c(24,19,36))
paste0("Hi here is the list of names: ",df1$Name,". I hope that works")
```

What the output becomes is:

[1] "Hi here is the list of names: John. I hope that works"

[2] "Hi here is the list of names: Steve. I hope that works"

[3] "Hi here is the list of names: Andy. I hope that works"

*But what I would like to get is:*

Hi here is the list of names: John, Steve, Andy. I hope that works"

Is there a way to paste the specific column reference like this but not have the repetition issue?

Comment: try this: ```paste0("Hi here is the list of names: ",paste0(df1$Name,collapse=","),". I hope that works")```

Comment: Are you interested in the paste or the printing? Seems you are interested in the latter thus would advice to use `cat` function

Answer (score 2):

You need to collapse `df$Name` into a single string before pasting it in. You can use another `paste()` call with the `collapse` argument, or you can use the handy `toString` function which automatically turns a length-n string into a length-1 string with commas and spaces, just like you want here.

```
paste0(
  "Hi here is the list of names: ", 
  toString(df1$Name),
  ". I hope that works"
)
# [1] "Hi here is the list of names: John, Steve, Andy. I hope that works"

## or 

paste0(
  "Hi here is the list of names: ",
  paste(df1$Name, collapse = ", ") ,
  ". I hope that works"
)
# [1] "Hi here is the list of names: John, Steve, Andy. I hope that works"
```

Sometimes I prefer `sprintf` to `paste` for fill-in-the-blank style string manipulation, it can be more readable:

```
sprintf(
  "Hi here is the list of names: %s. I hope that works", 
  toString(df1$Name)
)
# [1] "Hi here is the list of names: John, Steve, Andy. I hope that works"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `glue` and `toString` to do that in a single call:
`glue` is my go-to for dinamically generating strings that need to be filled with data.

```
library(glue)

glue("Hi here is the list of names: {toString(df1$Name)}. I hope that works")

Hi here is the list of names: John, Steve, Andy. I hope that works
```